# Ошибка в my_thread_global_end

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu, qt, qt5

Озадачился многопоточным использованием MySQL в Qt5. В соответствии со справочным описанием к `QSqlDatabase` в каждом потоке создаю отдельный инстанс обозначенного класса с уникальным наименованием подключения. Соединение закрываю перед самым выходом при завершении работы потока:

```
bool threadRun() {
    {
        QSqlDatabase db
            = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QStringLiteral("QMYSQL")
                , _connection_name);

        if(!db.isValid()) return false;

        db.setHostName(QStringLiteral("localhost"));
        db.setDatabaseName(_db_name);
        db.setUserName(_db_user);
        db.setPassword(_db_pswd);

        if(!db.open()) return false;

        /* ... SQL-запросы ... */

        db.close();
    }

    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(_connection_name);

    return true;
}
```

По большому счёту нареканий нет, но смущают появляющиеся в логах записи о некоей ошибке, которая скорее всего приводит к утечке ресурсов:

> Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit
>
> Error in my_thread_global_end(): 2 threads didn't exit

Очень похоже, что `my_thread_global_end()` - это территория MySQL-клиента, а не Qt. Кто сталкивался, прошу помощи в ликвидации проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, но это баг, и [баг именно в Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41483), не закрытый до сих пор. Проблема составная, но устранение даже одного первого пункта из двух обнаруженных Даниелем Адамски (Daniel Adamski) фактически исправляет самый критичный момент.

Поставив мьютекс на контроль за методами `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()` и `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase()`, становится возможно избежать конфликтной ситуации, когда неатомарно изменяемый счётчик подключений изменяется как попало, что в свою очередь приводит к undefined behavior или, проще говоря, к неопределённому поведению.