# Производительность Qt при работе с БД

Tags: c++, sql, qt, производительность

Имеет ли смысл отказываться от QtSql в пользу непосредственно API СУБД (в минималистичной обертке)? Насколько большую цену придется платить за удобство Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Преимуществ довольно много, а вот цена... Собственно невысокая, поскольку QtSql просто транслирует текст запроса в драйвер. Там ничего особо тяжёлого не производится. Единственная [проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452767/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-my-thread-global-end), которая до сих пор не решена внутри плагина, - это многопоточность. Приходится оборачивать в глобальный мьютекс каждое получение объекта класса `QSqlDatabase` из статических функций.