# Снижение количества блокировок мьютекса при доступе к БД

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt5

Опираясь на ранее заданный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452767/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-my-thread-global-end) и обнаруженный к нему ответ, создал глобальный статический мьютекс, которым регулирую многопоточный доступ к статическим методам класса `QSqlDatabase`: `addDatabase()`, `database()` и `removeDatabase()`.

```
#include <QtCore/QGlobalStatic>
#include <QtCore/QMutex>

Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(QMutex, _g_mutex)

static QSqlDatabase addDatabase(const QString &conn_name) {
    QMutexLocker locker(_g_mutex);
    return QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QLatin1String(DB_DRIVER), conn_name);
}

static QSqlDatabase database(const QString &conn_name) {
    QMutexLocker locker(_g_mutex);
    return QSqlDatabase::database(conn_name, false);
}

static void closeDatabase(const QString &conn_name) {
    QSqlDatabase db = database(conn_name);
    if(db.isValid() && db.isOpen()) db.close();
}

static void removeDatabase(const QString &conn_name) {
    QMutexLocker locker(_g_mutex);
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(conn_name);
}
```

Работает без ошибок, межпоточных конфликтов не возникает, однако следствием данной конструкции становится чрезмерное, на мой взгляд, количество выполняемых мьютексом блокировок. Дело в том, что объект `QSqlDatabase` - `implicit shared` и раздаётся в стеке, а чтобы выполнить запрос к БД необходимо сперва его получить. И когда создаётся объект `QSqlQuery` к нему всякий раз приходится вызывать собственный статический метод `database()`, представленный выше. Например:

```
bool MyDatabase::query(const QString &qstr) {
    QSqlQuery query(database(connectionName()));
    if(!query.exec(qstr)) return false;
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Метод `MyDatabase::query()` вызывается многопоточно, а отсюда появляется и множество вынужденных блокировок мьютекса, которых, по идее, можно было бы избежать, если иметь объект `QSqlDatabase`, существующий между вызовами `MyDatabase::query()`. Например:

```
class MyDatabase {
    public:
        MyDatabase() {}

        bool query(const QString &qstr);

    private:
        QSqlDatabase _db;
};
```

В этом случае получаем идеальный вариант, когда один раз при открытии соединения с БД блокируем мьютекс на короткое время, а уже далее пользуемся объектом `QSqlDatabase` без всяких блокировок и сопутствующих им тормозов.

Но тут снова проблема: ни один из объектов `QSqlDatabase`, связанный с конкретным соединением БД, не должен существовать непосредственно перед закрытием этого самого соединения. Далее примеры из справки Qt.

Неправильный вариант:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("sales");
QSqlQuery query("SELECT NAME, DOB FROM EMPLOYEES", db);
QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("sales");
```

... и правильный:

```
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("sales");
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT NAME, DOB FROM EMPLOYEES", db);
}
QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("sales");
```

Получается, нет иного выхода, кроме как создавать объект `QSqlDatabase` в куче, чтобы затем, когда он станет не нужен, корректно удалить. Но сколь верен будет этот вариант? Мне кажется, это будет идти вразрез с идеей использования `QSqlDatabase`. Буду признателен за содействие в разрешении сложившейся дилеммы. Возможно также, что существует альтернативный путь, который для меня не очевиден.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом. Создал приватный класс-обёртку `DatabasePrivate` над `QSqlDatabase` и поместил его в шаред-указатель. Обёртка нужна для того, чтобы не создавать объект `QSqlDatabase` в куче, поскольку нет уверенности в корректности данного подхода.

Заголовочный файл **database.h**:

```
#include <QtCore/QSharedPointer>

class DatabasePrivate;

class Database {
    public:
        Database() {}

        ~Database();

    private:
        QSharedPointer<DatabasePrivate> _d;
};
```

Нужно обратить внимание, что реализация деструктора вынесена из заголовочного файла в файл реализации. Это необходимо по той причине, что класс `DatabasePrivate` имеет предварительное объявление (`forward declaration`), тогда как шаблонному `QSharedPointer` требуется полная информация о контролируемом им объекте для корректного удаления.

Файл реализации **database.cpp**:

```
#include <QtCore/QGlobalStatic>
#include <QtCore/QMutex>

Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(QMutex, _g_mutex)

class DatabasePrivate {
    public:
        QSqlDatabase _db;

};

QSqlDatabase addDatabase(const QString &cname) {
    QMutexLocker locker(_g_mutex);
    return QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QStringLiteral(DB_DRIVER), cname);
}

void removeDatabase(const QString &cname) {
    QMutexLocker locker(_g_mutex);
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(cname);
}

void deletePrivateObject(DatabasePrivate *obj) {
    if(obj->_db.isValid()) {
        const QString cname
            = obj->_db.connectionName();

        if(obj->_db.isOpen())
            obj->_db.close();

        delete obj;

        removeDatabase(cname);
    }
}

Database::Database()
    : _d(QSharedPointer<DatabasePrivate>(new DatabasePrivate()
        , deletePrivateObject)) {}

Database::~Database() {}
```

Использование `QSharedPointer` создаёт проблему, которая возникает, если начать копировать объекты класса `Database`, например, через присваивание. Каждая копия объекта `Database` будет ссылаться на один и тот же объект `QSqlDatabase`. Если в деструкторе `Database` попытаться разорвать соединение с сервером БД, то оставшийся в живых объект `QSqlDatabase` станет невалидным.

По этой причине деструктор `Database` пуст, но используется специальная функция `deletePrivateObject(DatabasePrivate*)`, которая вставлена вторым аргументом при создании умного указателя, и будет вызвана только тогда, когда счётчик копий у `QSharedPointer` сравняется с нулём.

Таким образом достигнута полная автоматизация, не требующая отслеживания времени жизни последней копии объекта `QSqlDatabase` и корректно закрывающая соединение с БД.

Глобальный мьютекс теперь требуется только при открытии и закрытии соединения с БД. При выполнении же запросов просто используем сохранённый в `QSharedPointer` объект соединения.