# Qt + MySQL. Установление и закрытие соединения

Tags: mysql, qt

Добрый день.
Осваиваю работу Qt с БД MySQL. Прошу не смеяться сильно. Интересует, как правильно устанавливать и закрывать соединение с БД. К примеру, есть такой код:

```
void DBChooser::fillList()
{
    QSqlDatabase db;
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "connection");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setPort(3309);
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("123987");

    if(db.open())
    {
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.exec("SHOW DATABASES");
        while(query.next())
        {
            qDebug()<<query.value(0).toString();
        }

        db.close();
        QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("connection");
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Ошибка", db.lastError().text());
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Вопросы следующие:
1. Создание подключения можно осуществлять один раз за всю программу, а далее только открывать и закрывать соединение (`open()` и `close()`) для выполнения каждого запроса? Или весь приведённый выше текст нужен для обработки каждого запроса?
2. Назначение статического метода `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase()`? Если подключение закрыто `close()`, то зачем его ещё удалять из списка подключений? И что это за список подключений?
3. Как вообще грамотно построить архитектуру слоя доступа к БД?
 
Буду рад любым "крохам". Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Создание подключения можно осуществлять один раз за всю программу, а далее только открывать и закрывать соединение (`open()` и `close()`) для
>      выполнения каждого запроса? Или весь приведённый выше текст нужен для
>      обработки каждого запроса?

В Qt упор сделан именно на то, что однажды созданное подключение к базе данных продержится открытым если и не на протяжении всего жизненного цикла программы, то во всяком случае большую часть этого времени. Это удобный подход в том случае, если планируется однопоточный доступ к СУБД, однако создаёт определённого рода проблемы в случае многопоточного к ней обращения.

Также необходимо помнить, что однажды созданное подключение не остаётся в открытом состоянии бесконечно длительное время (если иное не переопределено в настройках сервера). Тем не менее `QSqlDatabase` для MySQL (собственно, как и для некоторых иных СУБД) [предоставляет возможность](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#setConnectOptions) производить переподключение в случае, если соединение будет закрыто по таймауту: `MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT=1`

Итого, если планируется однопоточный доступ к СУБД, то достаточно один раз создать подключение (возможно, с опцией переподключения) и далее пользоваться одним только им.

> 2. Назначение статического метода `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase()`? Если подключение закрыто `close()`, то зачем его ещё удалять из списка
>      подключений? И что это за список подключений?

Для того, чтобы до объекта подключения `QSqlDatabase` можно было легко добраться из любого места программы в Qt все экземпляры обозначенного класса хранятся в обычном статическом хэше:

```
static QHash<QString,QSqlDatabase> hash;
```

Ключом в хэше является строка с наименованием подключения, а значением, собственно, само подключение. Таким образом, добавляя при помощи метода:

```
QSqlDatabase QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(const QString &type
    , const QString &connectionName = QLatin1String(defaultConnection))
```

... новое подключение, его всегда будет возможно получить позднее, призвав на помощь другой метод:

```
QSqlDatabase QSqlDatabase::database(const QString &connectionName
    = QLatin1String(defaultConnection), bool open = true)
```

В свою очередь метод:

```
void QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(const QString &connectionName)
```

... всего лишь зачистит соответствующий элемент в хэше.

Однако у этого подхода имеется существенный недостаток: нельзя [начать удалять](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#removeDatabase) объект подключения до того момента, пока не будет ликвидирован последний из использующихся объектов `QSqlDatabase` того же подключения, а также связанные с ним `QSqlQuery`. Это проблема исходит из того, что при использовании `QSqlDatabase::database()` возвращается копия `QSqlDatabase`, содержащаяся в статическом хэше и разделяющая с ним одни и те же ресурсы.

Конечно, можно не вызывать метод `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase()`, ограничившись закрытием соединения, однако при активном переподключении к СУБД это приведёт к тому, что статический хэш будет разрастаться от неиспользуемых объектов `QSqlDatabase`, что уже само по себе отнюдь не есть гут.

> 3. Как вообще грамотно построить архитектуру слоя доступа к БД?

Зависит от того, как будет использоваться подключение(-я) к СУБД в программе. Если это однопоточный вариант, то можно особо не переживать и построить всё ровно так, как говорит об этом справка в Qt:

1. добавляем подключение через `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()` где-нибудь при старте программы;
2. работаем с запросами, устанавливая для них объект подключения, в свою очередь полученный посредством `QSqlDatabase::database()`;
3. вызываем `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase()` при выходе из программы.

Однако проблемы начинаются при многопоточном создании подключений. `QSqlDatabase` не поддерживает отправку запросов из иных потоков, кроме как из того, в котором был создан объект класса. Соответственно, если в программе задействуется сразу несколько потоков, то в каждом из них придётся создавать своё собственное подключение. Разумеется, что и удалять из хэша их придётся там же или иным хитрым образом, так как `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase()` хотя и объявлен потокобезопасным методом, таковым он на самом деле [не является](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452767/).

Для себя выработал пока единственное решение, которое более менее устраивает в сложившейся ситуации с многопоточным подключением - использование `QThreadStorage`.

Файл **databaseconn.h**:

```
#ifndef DATABASECONN_H
#define DATABASECONN_H

#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>

class DatabaseConn {
    public:
        static QSqlDatabase db();

};

#endif
```

Файл **databaseconn.cpp**:

```
#include <QtCore/QThreadStorage>
#include <QtCore/QReadWriteLock>
#include <QtCore/QSharedPointer>
#include <QtCore/QGlobalStatic>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QUuid>

#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>

#include "adatabaseconn.h"
```

Сначала защищаем статическим мьютексом доступ к трём основным методам, управляющим подключениями к СУБД.

```
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(QReadWriteLock, _g_rw_lock)

QSqlDatabase addDatabase(const QString &cname) {
    QWriteLocker locker(_g_rw_lock);
    return QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", cname);
}

QSqlDatabase database(const QString &cname) {
    QReadLocker locker(_g_rw_lock);
    return QSqlDatabase::database(cname, false);
}

void removeDatabase(const QString &cname) {
    QWriteLocker locker(_g_rw_lock);
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(cname);
}
```

Класс `DatabaseStorage` при создании своего объекта генерирует уникальное имя для нового подключения. Это особенно удобно в том случае, если используются скоротечные потоки, например, при задействовании `QtConcurrent`:

```
class DatabaseStorage {
    public:
        DatabaseStorage()
            : _cname(QUuid::createUuid().toString()) {}

        ~DatabaseStorage() {removeDatabase(_cname);}

        QString _cname;

};
```

Все экземпляры `DatabaseStorage` хранятся в статическом `QThreadStorage`. Он представляет собой, в целом, обычный контейнер, но при этом все элементы которого существуют и могут быть изъяты исключительно в соответствии с теми потоками, в которых были созданы:

```
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(QThreadStorage<QSharedPointer<DatabaseStorage> >, _g_storages)
```

Основной метод класса `DatabaseConn`, возвращающий экземпляры объектов подключений:

```
QSqlDatabase DatabaseConn::db() {
    // Если ранее в текущем потоке, в котором существует
    // контекст выполнения, уже было создано подключение,
    // то и возвращаем именно его.
    if(_g_storages->hasLocalData() == true)
        return database(_g_storages->localData()->_cname);

    // В обратном случае создаём новое подключение.
    QSharedPointer<DatabaseStorage> storage;
    storage.reset(new DatabaseStorage());

    QSqlDatabase db = addDatabase(storage->_cname);
    if(db.isValid()) {
        db.setDatabaseName("...");
        db.setUserName("...");
        db.setPassword("...");
        db.setHostName("...");
        db.setPort(3306);

        db.setConnectOptions("MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT=1");

        if(db.open()) {
            QStringList qstrs;
            qstrs.append("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");
            qstrs.append("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'");
            qstrs.append("SET SESSION collation_connection" \
                " = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'");

            QSqlQuery query(db);
            foreach(const QString &qstr, qstrs) {
                if(!query.exec(qstr)) {
                    QMessageLogger logger(__FILE__, __LINE__
                        , Q_FUNC_INFO, "DatabaseConn");

                    logger.warning() << qPrintable(query.lastError().text());
                    logger.debug()   << qPrintable(query.lastQuery());

                    return QSqlDatabase();
                }
            }

            // Сохраняем открытое подключение в хранилище.
            _g_storages->setLocalData(storage);

        } else {
            QMessageLogger(__FILE__, __LINE__
                , Q_FUNC_INFO, "DatabaseConn")
                .warning() << qPrintable(db.lastError().text());
        }
    }

    return db;
}
```

Необходимо отметить, что перед тем как поток завершит своё существование, обязательно будет вызван метод `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase()`, закрывающий в том числе и само соединение. Иными словами, обозначенный метод вызовет `QSqlDatabase::close()` самостоятельно.

Comment: Благодарю за исчерпывающий ответ. Многое пока не понятно, но буду разбираться, столько интересной информации.

Answer (score 1):

зачем открывать-закрывать все время? Один раз открыл и работай. Операция открытия и закрытия, относительно дорогая. Как и с файлами. Второе, метод removeDatabase служит для удаления соединения с конкретной базой данных. В программе их может быть несколько. Каждая под своим именем (у вас connection)

Comment: А сама MySQL разве не закрывает соединение по тайм-ауту? Период между обработками запросов может быть большой и мускуль закроет соединение, тогда его и понадобиться открывать заново.

Comment: может и закроет, если настроена. Но не замечал из коробки. Целый день сидит чел. за программой, вносит, ходит по кабинетам, на обед, с того же места работает.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что программа всё это время держит соединение? Может она опять же создаёт/закрывает их при каждом обращении к БД?

Comment: для меня и end user'a  как то по барабану по моему

Comment: Та я понимаю, что для юзера эти нюансы по-барабану, но мне (зайчатку программиста) нужно код писать. И мне нужно знать, открывать соединение каждый раз при обращении к БД или нет?

Comment: нет, конечно. Не помню что бы когда то такой проблемой заморачивался, лет за 20 именно в программах